# Postman request with ASP.NET Core API call is unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, postman

I just created an ASP.NET Core application and I am trying to test a Web API call that creates an item using the following controller method below. But I am following the instructions on this page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) which uses Postman to test the method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/asset")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Asset asset)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return null;
    }
    AssetItems.Add(asset);
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetAsset", new { id = asset.Id }, asset);
}
```

But when I make the request using Postman, I get the error:

> HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized You are not authorized to view this
>   page due to invalid authentication headers.

Comment: Check to see if authentication/authorization filter has been added to request pipeline. Could have been added based on the project template you used when creating project. Does the controller have an `[Authorize]` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if authentication/authorization filter has been added to request pipeline. Could have been added based on the project template you used when creating project.

If the controller has an `[Authorize]` attribute then removing it should allow requests through.

If however the Authorize filter was added globally then you may need to add an `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the action or controller to let requests through for that action or controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("api/asset")]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Asset asset) { ... }
```

Comment: I removed all [Authorize] attributes and added [AllowAnonymous] to my action but still does not work, get the same result. I did get more info on the error message, maye this might help: "This error occurs when the WWW-Authenticate header sent to the Web server is not supported by the server configuration. "

Comment: Then dont sent that header. remove it from the postman request

Comment: I tried removing the header and still, same results.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `launchsettings.json` (if you're running the API from the Visual Studio debugger), or your `web.config` (if you're running the API from IIS).

In my case, I had:

```
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
```

Updating `"anonymousAuthentication"` to `true` solved this issue for me.

---

I dont have a definitive reason as to why this solved the issue, but I believe your browser must acknowledge the fact you're authenticated on your machine and passes this to the API. However Postman does not know that you are authenticated on your local machine. Hopefully someone will be able to confirm if that's the case.